# Visual Studio convert web application to website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I know this is going backwards - but I would like to convert a web application back into a website. I want to do this because there are/will be many people working on it and we like to be able to update just a single page without having to compile/deploy the entire project.

My environment is Visual Studio 2012/ASP.Net 3.5/c#

Comment: Automate the deployment process and just deploy the whole thing.

Comment: There are better ways of doing it. User vcs and deployment tool (i.e. teamcity)

Comment: you can just remove project from Solution and then add existing Web Site and choose web site folder.

Comment: I recommend against using web site "projects". They're very unusual.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the standard way people work at my place.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me:

1. Delete the `.sln, .suo, .csproj, .csproj.user`, `*.debug.config`, `*.release.config` and any other project/solution related files.
2. In Visual Studio, choose `File -> Open -> Website` and browse to the project folder.
   The folder you want is typically the one where the `global.asax` and `default.aspx` pages are in (root).
3. Open it up.
4. Click on the newly generated Solution at the root of your Solution explorer.
5. Choose `File -> "Save xxxxxx.sln As..."` and save the new `*.sln` somewhere.
6. Rename your `App_Start` folder to `App_Code.`

These steps are just based on a quick experiment I did with a basic new WebForms web application project.

Depending on the complexity or type of your project, you may need additional steps.

In essence, you are just trying to strip away the "project" files and recreating a Solution file.

Comment: This is precisely what I'm attempting to do. I've gone through all the steps - but now what?

I tried launching this in VS but I get 'this site can't be reached'. Not sure what address to hit. Still trying https://localhost.

Going to try installing WAMP.

Comment: It worked for me but I just did two things more 1) Deleted all designer.cs files and 2) Replaced .aspx and .ascx file header attribute "CodeBehind" with "CodeFile"